# How to show these char like .｡･ﾟﾟ･(＞_＜)･ﾟﾟ･｡.(kaomoji) normally?

Tags: web, encode

I grab the some char from this web [kaomoji](http://kaomoji.ru/en/#joy).

I check the source code of the page and find it is encoded by `utf-8`.

But when I copy them in my `Chrome` and then paste in Vim, Vim can't show the char correctly like this and the encode of file is `utf-8`, too as shown at the bottom of the pic. Why this happened? How can I make these chars show normally in the text file?

[1215200040.bmp](http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/1215200040.bmp)

Comment: @enkryptor yeah, you're right when I use the `Batang` font. The char shows correct. Tnx, you can post below and I will take your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbols should be pasted as is. The most common cause you can't see them is the font you use doesn't have these symbols. Try using another font in Vim.